# why not increase performance by setting refresh interval in elasticsearch

Tags: performance, indexing, elasticsearch, bulkinsert

I watched the site memo about increasing indexing performance.
this is site [link](http://blog.sematext.com/2013/07/08/elasticsearch-refresh-interval-vs-indexing-performance/)

This link instruct me how to increase performance. but, it did not improve indexing speed in elasticsearch when I used to bulk python api with elasticsearch-py.

even all configuration change didn't affect bulk indexing performance.

i used parallel process or thread. max avg 30000 indexing per second.

what did i fault?

master node : 1
data node : 5 include master node
CPU : Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU           E5645  @ 2.40GHz
RAM : 32G

ES_HEAPSIZE : 10G

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It actually increase performance dramatically (more than 50% on my side). You just need to disable refresh_interval (enable it again when you finish indexing data)

```
curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/$INDEX_NAME/_settings" -d '{ "index" : { "refresh_interval" : "-1"  }}'

#index data......

curl -XPUT "http://localhost:9200/$INDEX_NAME/_settings" -d '{ "index" : { "refresh_interval" : "1s"  }}'
```